# Springs <form:Checkboxes> with titles

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring, jsp

My Question:

Is there a way i can add an infobox to a label which was created by the *form:checkboxes*-Tag? It should appear while hovering over the label (I know that the *title* attribute in html does exactly this).

Scenario:

I have a *div* with generated checkboxes. Those checkboxes have labels which are longer than the max-width of the containing *div*. As i don't want the width to be increased i thought displaying the name while hovering over the label would suffice. But as far as is know the *checkboxes*-Tag does not support a title-tag per item (items are computed at runtime and passed to the model).

It looks like this:

```
<fieldset>
  <div id="selectedAccounts" style="overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;" onchange="loadSthElse()">
    <form:checkboxes path="selectedAccounts" items="${accounts}" delimiter="</br>/>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

As items i pass a `Map<Integer,String>` to fill values and labels.

The [Spring Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.checkboxes) says that the standard html attribute `title` is still available. But i can't see if or how it is used for every single item that is created as you only seem to define one `title`.

I tried something like

```
$("#selectedAccounts label").each(function(element) {
  element.attr('title', element.name)
}
```

but it wouldn't work either.

Is there a way to make this work - Javascript, Jquery - or is the *checkboxes*-Tag poorly chosen?

Greetings,
Uwe

Comment: Welcome to SO. There is always a way. Show us some code you've written so we can give our advise based upon that, so that it will fit inside your project. Also we like to see your own effort at trying to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue.

I simply added a title using dojo after generating the checkboxes.

```
<div id = "selectedCampaigns" onchange="loadAdSets()">
  <form:checkboxes path="selectedCampaigns"  multiple="true" items="${campaigns}" delimiter="<br/>"/>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.query("#selectedCampaigns label").forEach(function(element) {
      dojo.setAttr(element,"title",element.innerHTML);
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

After setting the attribute to the `innerHTML` everything looks just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `title` attribute (¿WHY?), you can define `hover` event in any hidden object you want. It also gives your code and HTML structure more readability.

**HTML**

```
<form:input type="checkbox" value="CHECKBOX1" checked="checked">
<div>all the info you want to show when hovering your checkbox</div>
```

**CSS**

```
input+div{display:none;}
input:hover+div{display:inline;}
```

Comment: I would use `title`, if i could. But the checkboxes and following labels are generated dynamically, so i dont have much influence on that part and can't add a `div` with corresponding text.

Comment: you can define at least some `name`, `widgetVar`, id` or some unique identifier for the dynamically generated fields? if so you can make some workaround to show text on `hover` event...

Comment: it seems i can't add soething like that. But i may have a workaround using jQuery. I'll try it some more and post it here.